# TypeError: Cannot read property 'whenReady' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

i have a problem with electron.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'whenReady' of undefined

i use
node 14.0.1
electron 10.1.2

i run my app
"electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",

my background.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const { server } = require('feature-server-core')

server.start();

function createWindow () {
    // Создаем окно браузера.

    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1400,
        height: 900,
        minWidth: 1280,
        minHeight: 800,
        closable: true,
        center: true,
        type: "tool",
        titleBarStyle: "hidden",
    })

    win.menuBarVisible = false;
// и загружаем index.html в приложении.
    win.loadURL("google.com")
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()

    app.on('activate', function () {
        // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
        // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
    })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

Comment: Show us package.json.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cs579hnM my package.json

Comment: Take a look https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/issues/363.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Despite the fact that you are very good at English: Maybe check out https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Are you running the app from your code editor's terminal? Try using the system terminal instead (the `cmd` on Windows; Terminal on MacOS and Linux)

Comment: Also, check your `index.html` file and make sure you do NOT include `main.js` file in it

Comment: @AlexHoffman https://pastebin.com/SixNRAYE my index.html and my https://pastebin.com/sd0W56qu main.js

Comment: @AlexHoffman i run     "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build" or
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve" in webstorm IDE

Answer (score 5):

This is the problem related to directly calling the `'index.js'` with node like `node index.js`.
You need to use `electron index.js` or `electron .`(if your file is `index.js`)
electron is building your app.

Answer (score 4):

i solved the same problem just typing in the folder's terminal

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npm start` instead of `node .` to execute your application. If you are using an IDE you have to configure `npm` with the `start` option.

Answer (score 1):

1. check the js file is named the same in the package.json
2. check the script `"start": "electron ."` is in scripts.
3. npm i then npm start

that should help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom but the underlying problem was completely different from what you find elsewhere on the Internet. Normally, this issue comes from accidentally running `main.js` with `node` instead of `electron`. But in my case the problem was that the NTFS case sensitivity flag was set on the project folder and some subfolders because they were initially created using WSL. This lead to weird things like `electron.cmd` not being found due to Windows looking for `electron.CMD` with upper-case extension, etc., and apparently also some similar problem inside Electron itself which made it think we are not inside Electron after all, giving us the non-Electron version of `electron` which has no `app`.

The solution was to **create a copy of the whole project folder using Windows Explorer, and using that one instead of the original folder**. Windows Explorer doesn't preserve the case sensitivity flag, thus creating a copy of the folder clears the flag in all subfolders too. (You can then just delete the old folder.)

More information about case sensitivity in NTFS: https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/

---

Another cause could be having the environment variable `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1` set, maybe from some experiment or test a long time ago. Make sure this variable isn't set.